# Blank in drop-down list in options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to include a blank in my drop-down list using options_from_collection_for_select but cannot seem to put in the usual collection parameter `{ :include_blank => true}`. I cannot find a reference for this anywhere. Am I missing something?  My statement is:

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_from_collection_for_select(TaskGroup.all.order("LOWER(task_group_name)"), "id", "task_group_name",params[:search]) %>
```

Thanking you in advance for your help,

Leah

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= 
  select_tag( 
    "search",
    options_from_collection_for_select(
      TaskGroup.all.order("LOWER(task_group_name)"), "id", "task_group_name",params[:search]
    ), 
    :include_blank => true 
  )
%>
```

Comment: Perfect!   Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select(TaskGroup.all.order("LOWER(task_group_name)").map {|task_group| [task_group.task_group_name, task_group.id]}, params[:search]), {include_blank: "Select task group"} %>
```